# Shutting down a single log4net instance

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have multiple appenders in my log4net configuration, one for logging to a file, and the other using a stored procedure. I'm able to see the logging to a file, but the SQL data will show only after I click "Stop Site", see the image below:

[image]

So I've come to the conclusion that I may have to 'shutdown' the instance by doing the following: `log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("SearchParamsLogger").Logger.Repository.Shutdown();`

But in doing so, it seems to also shut down the other logger. **How can I shut down only the ONE logger?**

I have the following `logger` blocks:

```
<logger name="SearchParamsLogger">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogSearchParams" />
</logger>
<logger name="FileLogger">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
</logger>
```

I have the following appenders in my .config:

```
<appender name="LogSearchParams" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=MyServer\SQLEXPRESSPC;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=DBUser;Password=MyPassword" />
  <commandText value="InsertIManNrlLog" />
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserName"/>
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{uname}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@ObjectId" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@DeleteSpan" />
    <dbType value="Int32" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{deleteSpan}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@LogLevel" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
<appender name="LogFile" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="application.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header value="Logging Start &#xD;&#xA;"/>
    <footer value="Logging End &#xD;&#xA;"/>
    <conversionPattern value="%date | [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the number of messages the DBAppender will [buffer](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.BufferSize.html) before flushing them to the DB.

Your `<bufferSize value="100" />` is the default example I found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html), lower it and you should see the messages more often, you can even get immediate logging to the DB with the value 1 (or lower)

Comment: This was it!! Thanks! I gravely misunderstood the use of the bufferSize.